# Как правильно поздороваться с несколькими людьми в одном письме?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Хотел бы узнать, как правильно поздороваться с несколькими людьми (поприветствовать нескольких людей) в деловом письме.

Необходимо ответить сразу двум в одном письме, как правильно их поприветствовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Официальное письмо обычно начинается со слова *уважаемый*: "Уважаемые Иван Иванович и Петр Петрович!"

Более тепло и менее официально: "Дорогие Иван Иванович и Петр Петрович!"

Можно просто обратиться по имени и отчеству: "Иван Иванович и Петр Петрович!"

Вариант с приветствием: "Здравствуйте, (дорогие / уважаемые) Иван Иванович и Петр Петрович!" Это уже полуофициальный стиль.

Дружеское приветствие: "Привет, Ваня и Петя!" (не подходит для делового письма).

Answer (score 1):

Рад приветствовать вас, уважаемые... Либо : приветствую вас, уважаемые... Этот вариант более "сухой". Слово "приветствую" не определяет число, потому зачастую применяется в подобных ситуациях.

Comment: Это какой-то возвышенно-архаичный стиль.

Comment: В СПб до сих пор так принято здороваться, в том числе, в письмах.